# Use *ngIf with JSON

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

I'm creating an Ionic app using a JSON file.
Everything is ok for the moment, just when I want to use ngIf and JSON. I don't know how to use it... for example I want to do this :

```
<p *ngIf="{{item.price }}  == 1"> Okey </p>
<p> *ngIf="{{item.price}}  == 2"> Okey2 </p>
```

And in the json file if the value of the price is 1 it'll show "Okey".

I hope you understood me.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the brackets in the `*ngIf`-Statement.

```
<p *ngIf="item.price == 1"> Okey </p>
<p *ngIf="item.price == 2"> Okey2 </p>
```

Comment: Glad to help you. Can you accept the answer, please? it helps others to find the correct answer (and me for my reputation ;-))

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to surround the expression with the curly brackets `{{ }}`, but instead write it like this:

```
<p *ngIf="item.price === 1"> Okey </p>
<p *ngIf="item.price === 2"> Okey2 </p>
```